# How to sort spark countByKey() result which is in scala.collection.Map[(String, String),Long] based on value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

CSV table stored in location "/user/root/sqoopImport/orders"

```
val orders = sc.textFile("/user/root/sqoopImport/orders")
orders.map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(1),x(3)),1)).countByKey().foreach(println)
```

Here I am getting this result in unsorted based on key (String,String)

```
((2014-03-19 00:00:00.0,PENDING),9)
((2014-04-18 00:00:00.0,ON_HOLD),11)
((2013-09-17 00:00:00.0,ON_HOLD),8)
((2014-07-10 00:00:00.0,COMPLETE),57)
```

I want to sort so I have tried

```
orders.map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(1),x(3)),1)).countByKey().sortBy(_._1).foreach(println)
<console>:30: error: value sortBy is not a member of scala.collection.Map[(String, String),Long]
              orders.map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(1),x(3)),1)).countByKey().sortBy(_._1).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

`countByKey()` is an *action*. It finishes Spark calculation and gives you a normal Scala `Map`. Since `Map` is unordered, it makes no sense to sort it: you need to convert it to `Seq` first, using `toSeq`. If you want to stay in Spark land, you should use a transformation instead, in this case `reduceByKey()`:

```
orders.map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(1),x(3)),1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(_._1).foreach(println)
```

Also, please note that `foreach(println)` will only work as you expect in local mode: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the
 `orders.map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(1),x(3)),1)).countByKey()`

returns `Map[(String, String),Long]` in which we cannot apply `sortBy()` function

What you can do is

```
    val result = orders.map(_.split(",")).
         map(x=>((x(1),x(3)),1)).countByKey().toSeq

    //and apply the sortby function in new RDD
    sc.parallelize(result).sortBy(_._1).collect().foreach(println)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need to do parallelize I guess. You can use sortBy after you have changed to sequence.

Comment: Yes, we can use sortBy after changing to Seq, I just parallelized to get as a RDD.

Comment: @vishvaspatel34 I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

A Map is an unordered collection. You would need to convert that map into a collection that maintains order and sort it by key. ex:

```
val sorted = map.toSeq.sortBy{
  case (key,_) => key
}
```

Comment: I missed case, thanx it worked. can you please tell me why case ?

Comment: it is a common trick to get lambdas to work nicely with tuples